# How to register an application in Azure AD for my tenants using CSP Global Admin credentials?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, azure-ad-graph-api

My goal is to create an application in Azure Active Directory for my tenants using CSP Global Admin Account using C#.

As it is working through PowerShell commands.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount ==> CSP Global admin credentials
Select-AzureRmSubscription -TenantId "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx(Enter your Customer Microsoft ID)" ==> Select a tenant where I want to create application
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "SomePass@123" -asplaintext -force
New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "MyApp" -HomePage "http://MyApp" -IdentifierUris "http://MyApp" -Password $password ==> Application created in the above mentioned tenants account.
```

Please help me out doing the same in C#.

Comment: Take a look and let me know if you have any more query. Thanks

Comment: I wrote a code sample for you. Please have a check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static string postRequest(string url, string access_token, string data)
    {
        byte[] buffer = null;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "post";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
        //request.Headers.Add("other header", "it's value");
        if (data != null)
            buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        else
            buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("");
        request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
        request.GetRequestStream().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            return response.StatusCode + " " + reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }


    public class PasswordCredential
    {
        public string startDate;
        public string endDate;
        public string keyId;
        public string value;
    }

    public class AppConfiguration
    {
        public bool availableToOtherTenants;
        public string displayName;
        public string homepage;
        public List<string> identifierUris = new List<string>();
        public List<PasswordCredential> passwordCredentials = new List<PasswordCredential>();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string tenantId = @"customer tenant id";
        string resource = @"https://graph.windows.net/";
        string clientId = @"1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2";
        string returnUri = @"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

        var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId);

        var uri = new Uri(returnUri);
        var platformParams = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always);
        var authResult = context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, uri, platformParams).Result;
        var accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;

        var url = @"https://graph.windows.net/{customer_tenant_id}/applications?api-version=1.6";

        var passwordCredential = new PasswordCredential();
        passwordCredential.startDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ");
        passwordCredential.endDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ");
        passwordCredential.keyId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        passwordCredential.value = "TestPassword1.";

        var appConfiguration = new AppConfiguration();
        appConfiguration.availableToOtherTenants = false;
        appConfiguration.displayName = "MyApp";
        appConfiguration.homepage = "Https://MyApp";
        appConfiguration.identifierUris.Add("https://MyApp");
        appConfiguration.passwordCredentials.Add(passwordCredential);

        var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(appConfiguration);
        //Console.WriteLine(body);

        var result = postRequest(url, accessToken, body);
        Console.WriteLine(result);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

**I quickly created a sample for you using ADAL, Newtonsoft.Json and HttpWebRequest. You can try with this code snippet first.**

> **Update:** It is not suggested to hardcode your username and password. If you enable MFA, you may not able to get a token. If MFA
>   is disabled, you can try with the follwoing code snippet:

```
    string userName = @"xxxx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com";
    string passWord = @"password";

    var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id");

    result = context.AcquireTokenAsync(
          resource,
          clientid,
          new UserPasswordCredential(userName, passWord)).Result;
```

Comment: Thank this is exactly what I need but how can I hardcode my username and password to avoid that **Microsoft Login Prompt**

Comment: It is not suggested to hardcode your username and password. And if MFA is enabled, you will not be able to acquire a token successfully.

Comment: Since there are multiple CSP Accounts I will be passing username and password dynamically. and MFA is also disabled in all accounts. Hence I want it to be hardcoded, Kindly help me to achieve it.

Comment: @mohammedzaid Please check the update part of answer where I have explain how can you make that hard coded. Thanks

Comment: The clientid `string clientId = @"1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2";`mentioned is it global for everyone because I don't have any app registered by that clientid just a small doubt. Your willingness to help out wherever there is a need is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: @mohammedzaid Glad to hear you are most welcome, happy coding:)

Comment: @mohammedzaid Yes, it is global for everyone.

Comment: Thank you for the info:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Microsoft Graph API Beta version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-beta)  to create new application on azure portal

> **Note**  One of the following permissions is required to call this API. To learn more, including how to choose permissions, see
>   [Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference). see the screen shot below

[image]

**Request Format**

> https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications

**Update:**

I have tried this way:

Request From [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

Set the request body like below

```
{
  "displayName": "Your Application Name"
}
```

See the screen shot below

[image]

**Azure Portal:**

After successful response have checked on azure portal

[image]

> **Point to remember**
>
> If you tried with Microsoft Graph Explorer must set below permission.

See the screen shot below

[image]

For more information you could check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-beta)

> **Note:**  APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production applications is not
>   supported.

Comment: Thanks for your time. But I want to register an application in my **tenants** Azure AD account using **Microsoft partner center** global admin credentials.

Comment: Let me check with partner account then Will update my answer. I have tried with Microsoft Graph Explorer which works fine for me. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: Thank you for your response. Looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: @mohammedzaid I have updated the answer. you can try now.This example I have done with partner account with admin credential. check the example.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my query. I want to register an application to my partner center tenant's(Customer) account [Customer's Page](https://partner.microsoft.com/commerce/customers/list) this URL will List all tenants(customers). By using their id and Partner Center Admin Credential I should be able to register the application in their Azure AD as I'm able to do using the above PowerShell script. looking forward for your reply

Comment: @mohammedzaid Did you mean you wanted to create https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/account/v3/tenantmanagement tenant on azure active directory?

Comment: No, In [Customer's Page](https://partner.microsoft.com/commerce/customers/list) Select a customer and navigate to **Service Management** and click on Azure Active Directory you will be redirected to your Customer's Azure AD where you can create Applications, Users, Group on behalf of Customers Here I Just want to create Application. Same thing I want to achieve programmatically from C#. You can execute the above PowerShell script to understand my requirements and check in your customer Azure AD an application will be created.

Comment: Could you please have a try with the code snippet. I tested at my side, and it did the same thing as the PS script.